# using get_url with ansible 2.0.2 to download package

Tags: linux, yaml, ansible, ansible-2.x

i tried to download a package with get_url ansible but i have a problem. The url contain some variables so i wrote like this:

my playbook :

```
- name: download package
   vars:
     variable1: "foo"
     variable2: "baar"
     downloadurl:"http://example.com/{{variable1}}/path/{{variable2}}.tar.gz"

   tasks:
   - downloadPackage
```

and in the main.yml of downloadPackage

```
---
- name: downloadPackage
  get_url: url={{downloadurl}} dest=dest/to/path
```

i difined a variable(i tried both):

```
downloadurl: http://example.com/{{variable1}}/path/{{variable2}}.tar.gz
 downloadurl: "http://example.com/{{variable1}}/path/{{variable2}}.tar.gz"
```

but i couldn't download the package.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set a variable `downloadurl`, you can do it the simple way:

```
---
- name: downloadPackage
  get_url: url='http://example.com/{{variable1}}/path/{{variable2}}.tar.gz' dest='dest/to/path'
```

or

```
---
- name: downloadPackage
  get_url: 
    url: 'http://example.com/{{variable1}}/path/{{variable2}}.tar.gz'
    dest: 'dest/to/path'
```